# Access uniqueness on field level

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables : 
the first one is TEAMS

```
-----------------------------------
|id | teamID | teamName | ....... | 
-----------------------------------
```

AND the second is GAMES

```
-----------------------------------------
| id | team1ID(FK) | team2ID(FK) | Date |
-----------------------------------------
```

I need to prevent insert the same IDs to fields `team1ID, team2ID`

How can I do it ?

Comment: when you say access are you referring to ms-access? what rdbms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Microsoft Access 2007+, you can set a table-level check constraint.

Open the table in design view and click 'Property Sheet' in the Design ribbony-tab thing.

Then add a validation rule in the property sheet. In your case it would be [team1ID] <> [team2ID]

Comment: +1 In Access 2003 (no ribbony thing), you can right-click the title bar of the table design view window to get at the table's property sheet and set the validation rule.